# AS3 to get children in Gestureworks TouchSprite working

Tags: actionscript-3, button, gesture

Recently just trying around with the Gestureworks multitouch.
Here I have some problem about button inside a TouchSprite, below is my code:

```
package 
{
    import com.gestureworks.core.GestureWorks;
    import com.gestureworks.core.TouchSprite;
    import com.gestureworks.events.GWGestureEvent;
    import com.gestureworks.events.GWTouchEvent;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    public class Main extends GestureWorks
    {
        private var myDisplay:TouchSprite;

        public function Main():void
        {
            super();

            key = "xxx";

            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        }

        override protected function gestureworksInit():void
        {
            myDisplay = new TouchSprite();

            myDisplay.gestureReleaseInertia = true;
            myDisplay.gestureEvents = true;
            myDisplay.disableNativeTransform = false;
            myDisplay.disableAffineTransform = false;
            myDisplay.mouseChildren = true;
            myDisplay.gestureList = {"n-drag":true,"n-scale":true};

            myDisplay.addChild(boliviaMap);
            myDisplay.addChild(mapPink);
            addChild(myDisplay);

            myDisplay.addEventListener(GWGestureEvent.DRAG, gestureDragHandler);
            myDisplay.addEventListener(GWGestureEvent.SWIPE, gestureSwipeHandler);
            mapPink.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, tapPink);
        }

        private function tapPink(e:TouchEvent):void
        {
            trace("PINK");
            indicatorTxt.text = "PINK";
        }

        private function gestureDragHandler(event:GWGestureEvent):void
        {
            trace("g drag: ", event.value.dx, event.value.dy);
            event.target.$x +=  event.value.dx;
            event.target.$y +=  event.value.dy;
            indicatorTxt.text = "g drag: " + event.value.dx + " " + event.value.dy;
        }
    }
}
```

apparently the myDisplay.mouseChildren = true; will make myDisplay not able to drag or scale anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding your bigMap button set the mouseChildren property of myDisplay to true:

myDisplay.mouseChildren = true;

This should pass mouseEvents to objects inside.

Also, depending on the effect you want (I'm assuming this is for a multi-touch screen of somesort),  I'd suggest you should probably use a TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP on bigMap instead of MouseEvent.CLICK(MouseEvents arent multi-touch and won't be responsive if there is some kind of touch on another part of the screen at the same time).

Edit:

Assuming boliviaMap and mapPink aren't TouchMovieClips or TouchSprites then do something like this:

```
myDisplay.graphics.beginFill(0x555555, 1);  
myDisplay.graphics.drawRect(0,0,500,500);
myDisplay.graphics.endFill();
```

Then add your child assuming boliviaMap and mapPink are less than 500x500px:

```
myDisplay.addChild(boliviaMap);
myDisplay.addChild(mapPink);
```

Edit 2- A working example(for me anyways) combining TouchEvents with GWEvents:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.gestureworks.core.GestureWorks;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
    import com.gestureworks.core.TouchSprite;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;

    public class Main extends GestureWorks {

        public function Main() {
            super(); 
            key = "INSERT YOUR GW KEY HERE";
            Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        }

        override protected function gestureworksInit():void 
        {
            trace("GestureWorks has initialized");
            var myTouchSprite:TouchSprite = new TouchSprite();
            myTouchSprite.graphics.beginFill(0x555555,1);
            myTouchSprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
            myTouchSprite.graphics.endFill();
            myTouchSprite.gestureReleaseInertia = false;
            myTouchSprite.gestureEvents = true;
            myTouchSprite.disableNativeTransform = false; 
            myTouchSprite.disableAffineTransform = false;
            myTouchSprite.gestureList = {"n-drag":true, "n-rotate":true};   
            myTouchSprite.mouseChildren = true;

            var myTappableSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            myTappableSprite.graphics.beginFill(0xAD3059,1);
            myTappableSprite.graphics.drawRect(30,30,40,40);
            myTappableSprite.graphics.endFill();
            myTappableSprite.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, tappedThis);

            //myTouchSprite.addChild(myTappableSprite);
            myTouchSprite.addChild(myTappableSprite);
            addChild(myTouchSprite);
        }

        public function tappedThis(event:TouchEvent){
            trace("You tapped this");
        }
    }
}
```

I should also add that this will only work on a screen/device that triggers TouchEvents(if you're clicking myTappableSprite with a mouse it won't trigger the event).

Comment: Hi Drew, I've apply myDisplay.mouseChildren = true; and yah this time the button is work! But all the gesture are not working anymore, I can't scale or drag at all.

BTW, I've try the Gestureworks TAP function and also TouchEvent TAP...the TAP function is not working. Only mouse click can work. Tested with 2 multitouch devices.

Comment: Oh, for that I think you'll have to set: Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;                  This should go in the Main constructor(not in gestureworksInit) and you'll have to import flash.ui.Multitouch and flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode

Comment: Also, MovieClips, Sprites, Buttons ect. that are inside TouchSprites or TouchMovieClips that use mouseChilden = true don't respond to GW events.  You'll have to use TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP.  This is what worked for me anyways.  From talking with the GW support people though there is apparently an easier way to embed a TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip inside a parent TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip and have that work properly with the latest GW3 update.  I haven't tried this myself yet however.

Comment: Also I think this might have to do with the object bigMap taking up the entire size of the parent myDisplay.... if bigMap is 500x500px then make myDisplay 600x600px and placing bigMap inside it(only the outer 100px 'frame' of myDisplay will be responsive to GW events).

Comment: Hi Drew, I've updated my code above. I've try to change mouseEvent to TouchEvent and it is work for my touchscreen devices. But the myDisplay.mouseChildren = true; still making myDisplay not able to use the n-drag & n-scale from GW3. Is it I need to make my MovieClip button to be a TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip? And I not that understand about the extra 100px. Very disappointed to the GW3 support team as they haven get back to me after 48 hrs already.

Comment: What type of objects are boliviaMap and mapPink?  The GW people have said in the newest update that putting 1 layer of TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip into a TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip should work, but when I was working with GW3 this wasn't possible.  My workaround involved using regular Sprite/MovieClip/Button objects inside my TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip.

Comment: The TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip parent has to be larger than the child that's put inside it though.  This is what I mean by the 100px... you need to make a 'frame' around the child such that everything around it works with the GWGestureEvents, the child will only respond to TouchEvents.

Comment: Check my edited answer for an example of what I mean by that.

Comment: boliviaMap and mapPink is the instance name of 2 MovieClip that on stage. So you able to make your child in TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip clickable? I've change all my listener to TouchEvents and with mouseChilden=true, but only TouchEvents object is touchable, the parent TouchSprite is not dragable or scalable anymore. Too bad the support team haven't get back to me since last week. So disappointed after I bought the license.

Comment: Hi @Drew_TwistedPair , I still can't make it work from your updated code. Once I've added the mouseChilden=true, then all the TOUCH_TAP is not working anymore. Now I'll try to make all my child to TouchSprite/TouchMovieClip and see how it work out.

Comment: Hi, BTW, I need to use **Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE** because the GW3 **n-swipe** or **n-flick** is not working, not sure why yet, do u have any idea? and also if I use **Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE**,then cant use together with **Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;** right? then how can I use the **TOUCH_TAP**?

Comment: I updated my answer again, this time with a full example, hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Hi Drew, still the same. Once we have **mouseChilden=true** then the touchsprite is not touchable anymore. anyway, thanks for your help! very appreciate, I'll keep find out is there any other solutions. THANKS!